# is there a way to calculate mix-blend-mode (css) for svg element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mix-blend-mode

We have a simple svg composed of 5 shapes . We want to "mix-blend-mode" this svg with a layer color. However this css property is not working on internet explorer. Is there a way to calculate what would be the result for each shape of our svg?

```
svg:
element1: red
element 2: blue
element 3: pink
element 4: white
element 5 :black
```

There is no transparency.

Comment: Presumably you could do [what the spec says](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode)

Comment: you could use an svg filter to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems possible as said in comments.

https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode